# Trying to use "%%timeit" to get time of cell execution but it outputs "` not found."

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, timeit

I am trying to test the speed of a cell's execution using "%%timeit" but it is not working as expected. All it ever prints is "`not found".

What's going on?

Here is a screenshot to show you what I see:

[image]

I am using python 3.6.10 and am using a jupyter notebook environment in vscode.

Comment: I feel like the Jupyter environment in VSCode is kinda lacking features in general. You should probably use the "regular" standalone Jupyter

Comment: okay yeah it is a problem with VScode. Works using normal jupyter notebook. Too bad b.c. I find using VSCode to be quite convenient

Comment: `%timeit` works for me, but it differs considerably from vscode's cell execution time.

Comment: With VSCode 1.80.1 and python 3.9.15 (Anaconda) `%%timeit` works flawlessly for me